# Make Monit Wait When Shutting Down Processes

Tags: java, deployment, monit

I need to shut down a group of java processes and then restart them as part of a deployment process we have using bamboo. Monit returns back quite fast, which doesn't let the build script know to wait for all of the processes to end. Is there any way to make monit wait before returning from stopping those processes?